# Should I be concerned about this rust on the roof flashing

Tags: roof, flashing, rust

[image]

[image]
That top part is where I tried rustoleum rust converter after sanding it down a little.

Is there anything I can do. Should I even worry? That rustoleum converter was 2 years ago and I did just that one part. But life got in the way.

Comment: How old is the roof?

Comment: @Jack 12 years I believe. We replaced it in 2006

Comment: Is the metal supposed to be galvanized, and is it rusty up under the shingles or just to the edge and maybe a 1/2" under?